# How to reload a Component after sending some data to server?

Tags: angular, typescript, nativescript, nativescript-angular

I'm creating a a cross-plaform app. I have a TabView Component that has to refresh a tab after sending some value to the server. When I log in ngOnInit dynamically set the content of my tab but when I send the data to the server and I navigate to the summary page ngOnInit is no longer called so the content never change. 
Any idea?

**Here is part of my code**

*home.component.ts*

```
ngOnInit(){
 this.homeService.getPrenotazioni().subscribe((res) => {
  var layout = <StackLayout>this.page.getViewById("prenotazioni");
  //...set content...
 };
}
```

*tabs.component.html*

```
<GridLayout>
    <TabView androidTabsPosition="bottom">
        <page-router-outlet *tabItem="{title: 'Home'}" name="homeTab"></page-router-outlet>
        <page-router-outlet *tabItem="{title: 'Prenota Ritiro'}" name="prenotaritiroTab"></page-router-outlet>

         <!-- other tabs -->
    </TabView>
</GridLayout>
```

When I send data from the "Prenota ritiro" tab and I go to the "Home" tab I want to refresh the content of the "Home" tab

Comment: Tabs are initiated only once, so you won't get `ngOnInit` every time. With Angular templates you already have the flexibility to update your UI by updating your data that binds to. Simply listen to `selectedIndexChanged` event, hit the service for current tab based on tab index.

Comment: I know that `ngOnInit` is called once, but i didn't find another way to reload the content so I asked if it could be done

Answer (score 0):

Did you consider using onSameUrlNavigation in your router config?  If you are using the router-outlet in the tab you should be able to make this work.

```
@ngModule({
 imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes, {onSameUrlNavigation: ‘reload’})],
 exports: [RouterModule],
 })
```

Comment: Yes, but maybe I use it on the wrong way. I'll try again and tell you if it worked

Comment: I'm using `NativeScriptRouterModule` is it the same?

Comment: Sorry, I didn't read carefully your answer. I'm using page-router-outlet because I have a login component which redirects to a TabView component

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like the nativescript page and angular component life cycle are not the same.  What about setting the subscription in the navigatingTo event of the page?

https://docs.nativescript.org/ui/ns-ui-widgets/page

Comment: You mean add this?
`<Page 
      navigatingTo="onNavigatingTo">
</Page>`

Comment: I've add the event but when I change the tab, the onNavigatingTo (the same shown on https://github.com/NativeScript/nativescript-sdk-examples-js/blob/master/app/ns-ui-widgets-category/page/page-events/page-events-ts-page.ts) function is never called.

Comment: I avoided the problem by moving the `ngOnInit` code to other functions that are called both in `ngOnInit` and in a `PullToRefresh`. Thanks anyway!